# How to cancel once-mentioned element in thermochemical reactions

Tags: thermodynamics

If I have three thermochemical reactions in a series(in order to find the enthalpy change) how can I cancel an element having not included in the reaction that's being asked about?

and only mentioned in one of the reactions ( either products or reactants)

e.g: $$\ce{NO + O3 \rightarrow NO2 + O2}$$
     $$\ce{O3 \rightarrow 3/2 O2}$$
     $$\ce{O2 \rightarrow 2O}$$

**The reaction that is being asked**: $$\ce{2NO2 \rightarrow 2NO + O2}$$

Comment: Woild you be so kind as to [format](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) 
 mathematical expressions and equations using $\LaTeX$? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation "LaTex at ‎chemistry.SE") to find out how to make your future posts better.‎

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of this formula: $$\Delta H = \Sigma ~\Delta H_f~(\text{products}) - \Sigma ~\Delta H_f~(\text{reactants}) $$

Take $\ce{O3 \rightarrow \frac{3}{2} O2}$ into consideration. Ozone molecule is the less stable form of O. If you know that how much the $\Delta H$ for that reaction is, you can in fact predict the $\Delta H_f$ for $\ce{O3}$. If you're interested, [wikipedia has documented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_change_of_formation_%28data_table%29) some of the enthalpies of formation. Notice that the most thermodynamically stable form of the element is considered to have $\Delta H_f = 0$.

Now that the $\Delta H_f$ for ozone is determined, you can apply the formula above for the first reaction: ($x$ is $\Delta H$) $$x = (\Delta H_f \ce{(NO2)} + 0) - (\Delta H_f (\ce{NO}) + \Delta H_f (\ce{O3}))$$

So, from the equation above we can conclude that $$x + (\Delta H_f (\ce{NO}) + \Delta H_f (\ce{O3})) = (\Delta H_f \ce{(NO2)}) $$

Now write the master formula for the last reaction: $$(2 * \Delta H (\ce{NO}) + 0) - 2 * \Delta H_f (\ce{NO2})$$

What did we conclude from the last reaction? $x + (\Delta H_f (\ce{NO}) + \Delta H_f (\ce{O3})) = (\Delta H_f \ce{(NO2)}) $ Assuming that $x$ is at hand, do you really need to know the $\Delta H_f$ for $\ce{NO}$ & $\ce{NO2}$?

Comment: Also, you could reverse the asked reaction. The difference in the enthalpy change that it would have with the reaction one will be equal to the formation of $\ce{O3}$. But you should be careful about the negative and positive enthalpy sign.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just interested in the reaction enthalpy of the reaction

$$\ce{2NO2 <=> 2NO + O2}$$

and one set of equations for the calculation of $\Delta H_f(\mathrm{products})$ and/or $\Delta H_f(\mathrm{reactants})$ doesn't work out, just use another one.

**It does not matter! The Hess Law is invariant of the path.**